# Why do I get error everytime I'm using SfCalendar() Widget? I already inputted the dependencies

Tags: flutter

"Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Unable to load asset: packages/timezone/data/2020a.tzf)". I can't simply run the SfCalendar widget. Here's my code:

```
    return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      'Calendar View',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF57A0D3),
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: SfCalendar(
      view: CalendarView.month,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Have you run `flutter clean` and restarted your app?

Comment: tried both but it doesn't work

Comment: somehow it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `flutter clean` and restart the app then do `flutter pub get` in terminal. It works on me